# Storing SFTP zip files as objects rather than downloading the file

Tags: r, sftp, rstudio-connect

The goal is to store an object that can then be stored as a pin on R Studio Connect. I would prefer not to download the file on my local machine as this is a manual step. I want to automate the pulling of the data using the SFTP connection.

I currently am able to download files from my SFTP connection using the sftp package in r. After some research, I was able to create an object using this code:

```
connection <- sftp::sftp_connect(
  server   = "host_server.com",
  folder   = "/file/folder",
  username = "user_name",
  password = "password",
  protocol = "sftp://",
  port     = 22,
  timeout = 30)

fileurl <- paste0(connection$url, "/", "filename.csv.zip")
port    <- as.integer(connection$port)
userpwd <- connection$userpass
timeout <- connection$timeout

test <- RCurl::getBinaryURL(url = fileurl,
                            port = port,
                            userpwd = userpwd,
                            connecttimeout = timeout,
                            .opts = list(),
                            dirlistonly = FALSE)
```

At the moment, I'm stuck on how to then transfer this object to something that can be read by humans. Is there a step that I'm missing in between since the file that I'm trying to retrieve is a zip file?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/unzip

Comment: I don't think this will help since unzip requires a zip name argument which requires me to download the file on my local machine. This is not the goal. Could you explain how this might help?